# How stable is the microsoft azure compute emulator?

Tags: azure, azure-emulator

My organization is difficult at a policy level. I have an opportunity to create an app that is appropriate as a Worker Role. Using Azure or Azure Stack/Pack is out of the question because of the insanity of the Security folks. I might be able to use Azure Compute Emulator so as to position the customer for the future. My question is: Is Azure Compute Emulator stable ? Will it run by itself for long periods of time ? Does it start roles automatically ? Does it leak memory , etc. ? I welcome comments/opinions/alternatives on this - **however my hands are tied by IA -- it is what it is and I can't change it. Please do not send comments about whether or not this is a good idea - my only alternative is IIS Roles.**   If this works, it may provide an option to do PaaS inside Dockers.*

Comment: why are security folks paranoid of a private cloud thing? you should fire them and get proper ones. anyway, why would you use azure compute emulator if you don't plan on using azure??

Comment: This is completely off-topic: you're soliciting opinions on an emulator. Something that has never been intended for any type of long-term / production runs. I have no idea what you mean by "my hands are tied" - if you're suggesting someone is telling you to run a production workload on a dev/test emulator, then you are not using the cloud: you're simply doing something you should not do (with a tool that won't offer you any SLA).

Comment: Further: How can Azure Stack be out of the question, yet a developer tool be considered as a production platform (a tool that doesn't even emulate anything outside of web/worker roles and storage). This makes zero sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparantly, my question is not as insane as others indicated.

These guys have the same kind of issues I have and created LightBlue and Azure emulator.
https://github.com/LightBlueProject/LightBlue